# How do I get JavaPoet to generate a class literal?

Tags: java, javapoet

I want to use JavaPoet to generate an annotation with a type literal as value. For example:

```
@AutoService(MyService.class)
public class GeneratedClass implements MyService {
}
```

I've tried all the options I can think of, but none work:

```
TypeSpec.classBuilder("GeneratedClass")
    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
    .addSuperinterface(MyService.class)
    .addAnnotation(
        AnnotationSpec.builder(AutoService.class).addMember(
            "value", "$L", MyService.class
        ).build()
    )
```

using `$L` generates `interface MyService`

using `$T` generates `my.package.MyService`, which is close but misses the `.class` part.

using `$N` gives an error: `expected name but was my.package.MyService`

how do I get it to generate `MyService.class` as the annotation value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
TypeSpec.classBuilder("GeneratedClass")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
            .addSuperinterface(MyService.class)
            .addAnnotation(
                    AnnotationSpec.builder(AutoService.class).addMember(
                    "value", "$T.class", MyService.class).build()
            ).build();
```

Comment: I don't know other way to do it. I suppose it was recommended because  `format` is a `String` not an `Enum`.

Comment: What about when you're dealing with a `ParameterizedTypeName`?